# How to open an extension from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

is it  possible to launch an extension from javascript?

for example in my code i check if a specific keyword is in the url with:

```
let keyword = "xyz"

if (window.location.href.indexOf("keyword") > -1) {
            window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/");
        }
```

and if it is in the url, i get redirect to google.com

the problem is that if i try to open my index.html, it opens it as a website instead of an extension popup

so how can you open it as an extension, if you can?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `chrome.runtime.getURL('path/to/file')`.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL

Also keep the `web_accessible_resources` in your `manifest.json` in mind when using this.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/